# uploading image to django rest model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-file-upload

I am trying to upload image to Images folder which under the media directory. I am using following APIView on my views.py;

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request, format='jpg'):
        up_file = request.FILES['file']
        destination = open('C:\\Users\\cano\\Desktop\\workspace\\campusBackend\\campusBackend\\media\\Images', 'wb+')
        for chunk in up_file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
            destination.close()
            return Response(up_file.name, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

However, when I sent request, it gives me the following error;

```
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> 'C:\\Users\\cano\\Desktop\\workspace\\campusBackend\\campusBackend\\media\\Images'
> [12/Dec/2016 15:10:45] "POST /imageUpload HTTP/1.1" 500 19170
```

I have already added MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in settings.py;

```
> MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
> 
> MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
destination = open('C:\\Users\\cano\\Desktop\\workspace\\campusBackend\\campusBackend\\media\\Images' + up_file.name, 'wb+')
```

With your code you are trying to rewrite a directory not a file.

Comment: I added the new file name at the end, and it fixed my problem thank you